# SSL configuration CentOS 7

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

When trying to start httpd service the following error is shown

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See 
"systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When viewing the log files, the following appears in "ssl_error_log" file:

```
[Fri Jul 16 14:33:01.773030 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 5274] AH02203: Init: Private key 
not found
```

Clearly the key file is in the right directory and not empty, so what is the meaning of such error?

Additional Information:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/testvm_am_com_cert.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/testvm.am.com.key
```

ls -l /etc/pki/tls/private

```
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2748 Jul 14 20:02 testvm_am_com_cert.cer
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1704 Jul 14 20:04 testvm.am.com.key
-rw-------. 1 root root 1675 Jul  5 15:45 localhost.key
```

Comment: Clearly something is misconfigured, but without seeing your configuration, nobody can comment. An internet search for ah02203 may help; there are plenty of hits.

Comment: You could prove (to us) what the configuration file says (the value of SSLCertificateKeyFile) as well as an `ls -l` on that corresponding path.

Comment: Additional information is posted.

Comment: Is SELinux running in enforcing mode or not?

Comment: If SELinux is running in enforced mode (`getenforce` returns `"Enforcing"` ), then please post the output of `ls -laZ /etc/pki/tls/private` and `ausearch -ts today -m avc -i | grep key`.

Comment: Permissive mode.

Comment: Should I generate a new key? though "openssl rsa -in testvm.am.com.key  -check -noout" returns "RSA key ok"